# EMV Issuer Authenticate in second generate AC

Tags: smartcard, emv, mastercard

I am just new in EMV payment industry and currently doing some EMV payment development, and hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm seeing. I'm running the Mastercard M-TIP tests that apply to our solution, and I'm seeing some unexpected results. When running the M-TIP06 Test 02, I am getting an error of Issuer Authentication Failed. Our solution is online-only terminal which all the transactions shall go online and approved by host. In our testing, the transaction approved by host (returned with an Issuer Authentication Code and Authorization Code (00 - Approved)). However the card tends to answer the response with AAC in second generate and indicating that issuer authentication was failed. The AIP of the test card indicate that External Authentication is not required so I assume the Issuer Authentication Data should be included in second generate AC. I've attached the 1st and 2nd generate AC request and response.

```
    1st Generate AC (ARQC)
        Request : 80 AE 80 00 25 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 64 80 00 00 80 00 07 64 21 03 01 00 4A DC F0 6E 21 00 00 1E 03 00 58 00
            Class    :80
            Ins      :AE
            P1       :80
            P2       :00
            Lc       :25
            Data     :00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 64 80 00 00 80 00 07 64 21 03 01 00 4A DC F0 6E 21 00 00 1E 03 00 58 00
                Tag 9F 02: Transaction Amount                                             : 00 00 00 00 40 00
                Tag 9F 03: Cashback Amount                                                : 00 00 00 00 00 00
                Tag 9F 1A: Terminal Country Code                                          : 07 64
                Tag 95   : Terminal Verification Results (TVR)                            : 80 00 00 80 00
                Tag 5F 2A: Transaction Currency Code                                      : 07 64
                Tag 9A   : Transaction Date                                               : 21 03 01
                Tag 9C   : Transaction Type                                               : 00
                Tag 9F 37: Unpredictable Number                                           : 4A DC F0 6E
                Tag 9F 35: Terminal Type                                                  : 21
                Tag 9F 45: Data Authentication Code                                       : 00 00
                Tag 9F 34: Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results                   : 1E 03 00
                Tag 9B   : Transaction Status Information(TSI)                            : 58 00

        Response: C0 77 29 9F 27 01 80 9F 36 02 02 01 9F 26 08 3B 84 CB F3 33 26 6E A6 9F 10 12 02 10 A0 00 0F 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 90 00
            Ack Byte : C0
            Data     : 77 29 9F 27 01 80 9F 36 02 02 01 9F 26 08 3B 84 CB F3 33 26 6E A6 9F 10 12 02 10 A0 00 0F 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
                Tag 77   : Response Message Template Format 2                             
                    Tag 9F 27: Cryptogram Information Data (CID)                              : 80
                    Tag 9F 36: Application Transaction Counter (ATC)                          : 02 01
                    Tag 9F 26: Application Cryptogram (AC)                                    : 3B 84 CB F3 33 26 6E A6
                    Tag 9F 10: Issuer Application Data [M/Chip 4]                             : 02 10 A0 00 0F 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
            SW1 SW2  : 90 00 (SW_OK)

    2nd Generate AC (TC)
        Request : 80 AE 40 00 13 60 2D D5 A6 14 D6 00 00 00 12 30 30 80 00 00 80 00 58 00
            Class    :80
            Ins      :AE
            P1       :40
            P2       :00
            Lc       :13
            Data     :60 2D D5 A6 14 D6 00 00 00 12 30 30 80 00 00 80 00 58 00
                Tag 91   : Issuer Authentication Data [M/Chip]                            : 60 2D D5 A6 14 D6 00 00 00 12
                Tag 8A   : Authorization Response Code                                    : 30 30
                Tag 95   : Terminal Verification Results (TVR)                            : 80 00 00 80 00
                Tag 9B   : Transaction Status Information(TSI)                            : 58 00
        MChip4 - Symbol 81: Issuer Authentication failed, declining transaction

    Get Response
        Request : 00 C0 00 00 2B
        Response: C0 77 29 9F 27 01 00 9F 36 02 02 01 9F 26 08 54 A4 CD EF 87 20 FE B1 9F 10 12 02 10 20 10 0F 24 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 90 00
            Ack Byte : C0
            Data     : 77 29 9F 27 01 00 9F 36 02 02 01 9F 26 08 54 A4 CD EF 87 20 FE B1 9F 10 12 02 10 20 10 0F 24 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
                Tag 77   : Response Message Template Format 2                             
                    Tag 9F 27: Cryptogram Information Data (CID)                              : 00
                        Byte 1 bit 8-7 = 00     AAC
                               bit 6-5 = 00     Payment System specific cryptogram
                               bit 4   = 0      No advice required
                               bit 3-1 = 000    No information given
                    Tag 9F 36: Application Transaction Counter (ATC)                          : 02 01
                        Decimal value = 513
                    Tag 9F 26: Application Cryptogram (AC)                                    : 54 A4 CD EF 87 20 FE B1
                    Tag 9F 10: Issuer Application Data [M/Chip 4]                             : 02 10 20 10 0F 24 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
                        Key Derivation Index      = 02
                        Cryptogram Version Number = 10
                        Card Verification Results (CVR)  = 20 10 0F 24 04 00
                        DAC                       = 00 00
                        Counters                  = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
            SW1 SW2  : 90 00 (SW_OK)
```

As you can see the when second generate AC, it shows that **MChip4 - Symbol 81: Issuer Authentication failed, declining transaction**. If someone could provide insight into what's happening or what's going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your ARPC cryptogram in the Tag 91: Issuer Authentication Data seems wrong as it having 00 00. Could be issue with host simulator which generate ARPC or its translation to card.

Comment: I get the value from DE 55 in iso response (910A602DD5A614D60000001271349F18008605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E000008), and which response code '00' which mean this transaction approved online by host.

Comment: I rate this question down as the necessary card traces and CIS messages dumps are not provided.

Comment: @iso8583.infosupport I updated this question in another post, u may visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470834/card-returned-aac-in-second-generate-ac-even-online-host-approved-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something is wrong with your interface to MAS.

Apart from problem with Issuer Authentication you have another one with Issuer Scripts - your issuer script do not contain MACs and are not correct commands. It's strange you haven't attempted to send them, but you would get errors that should result in setting a bit in TVR.

I would recommend checking your MAS logs to see if your ARQC verification passes - I would assume it does not. Its either you have your MAS misconfigured and profile is not detected correctly (but it generated scripts so it wouldn't be the case, but still someone might have modified IMK-AC key value) or your data supplied for authentication are not integral with card-terminal interface.

You should check if everything is passed exactly as to the card but I'd start with checking PSN (tag 5F34 that is mapped to field 23) - it's a common mistake to omit it and because it is used in session key derivation process lack of this element results in cryptogram verification failures for cards with a nonzero value (this MTIP card profile has it set to 03 when I checked my logs). It's a common mistake that doesn't get noticed immediately as many cards (without PSN or zero value PSNs) work.

Please do not be suggested by response code in the test environment as it is a default response, even when completely everything is wrong with the data but testing script does not clearly require transaction to be online declined.

Comment: Hi, may I know is that the issuer script processing will cause the card return AAC in second generate AC? I haven't finish that part because still I am not really familiar in how to generate and compute MAC. For ARQC verification, I can attached the ISO response logs.

Comment: Response:
 [3]        000000
 [4]        000000004000
 [11]       235218
 [12]       102004
 [13]       0219
 [24]       0111
 [37]       105003235218
 [38]       325210
 [39]       00
 [41]       82298019
 [55]       910A602DD5A614D60000001271349F18008605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E0000088605841E000008

Comment: From the response, it shows host should approved transaction online. So, second generate AC will be a TC but the card decline it with an AAC, I am not sure which part that cause the card reject it, either incompletion of issuer script processing or wrong data sent to host? 
* AIP in this scenario indicate that External Authenticate is not supported, so the IAD could be sent along with AC command

Comment: @KennedyTan The issuer script processing does not require any modification to sent commands on terminal side. It should be generated by the issuer system. Please attach both request and response. Have you checked PSN?

Comment: @KennedyTan Issuer Authentication done explicitly is not used by Mastercard - there is only implicit Issuer Authentication that is not reflected in AIP. Still, card controls this process and responds accordingly to its risk management parameters and information about this may be retrievable from CVR that is part of 9F10, but card application specific.

Comment: You may find the iso request and response here [ISO Request & Response](https://asiapay-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/kennedy_tan/ERmDyJuLoj5PmbCcwqA0C-YBWDxDKFrGluHeelnzg26t8w?e=okPM7d)

Comment: Yup, I checked PSN for this card and it is '0009', obtained from ICC application. Is it correct?

Comment: @KennedyTan Is it really from the same device? It does seem you might be sending some pretty messy things in your messages if so. I don't know what is your device protocol and what is the meaning of field 23 there, but it seems different than what is in 5F34. Is this used as PSN or something different? Also: 1. Why is your CID (9F27 equal to 40 when you received ARQC from card), 2. Why is your TVR different than what you showed in card log? 3. Why is your Terminal Type equal to 22 when you sent 21 to the card?

Comment: opps, I don't notice the data is actually not sync. Thanks for that. Anyway do u meant the data in field 23 should be exactly same in 5F34?

Comment: Not necessarily - it much depends on what is your terminal-host protocol. In most ISO8583 implementations, it is PSN/CSN, so should be equal to what you get from 5F34 and absent when 5F34 is not available (it's an optional element).

Comment: I synced all the message data and now it is read from ICC card. However, the result is still same, card rejects the second generate AC with AAC. I would greatly appreciate it if you can have a look on the [ISO log](https://asiapay-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/kennedy_tan/Eb4QnPPx9YJImJWgu8YmvdoBWmHNRGaAeO-Ayn2_nhz_RQ?e=OQLDBP) and [Test Result log](https://asiapay-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/kennedy_tan/Ec6leMqASixBnY2Vdwi86OcBx0panYu9xxc_WiSfsWCA6Q?e=tPar8p). Thanks